# vim plugin does not work after migration from Centos6 to Centos7

Tags: vim, plugins, centos7

I have troubles with the vim plugin `Oscan` after migration from Centos6 to Centos7 on my workstation.

This plugin uses `ctags` to navigate between symbols and so on.
When I try to use it, it shows the following errors:

```
[ 0scan ] Vim(help):E149: Sorry, no help for help.txt
Error detected while processing function railmoon#oscan#open:
line  139:
E121: Undefined variable: edit_line_window
line  140:
E121: Undefined variable: s:available_tags_window
line  141:
E121: Undefined variable: s:result_window
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I can't figure out what changed in syntax after migration to Centos7.

What should I change in this plugin to make it workable? Is this problem with the plugin or vim?

This plugin on the official vim site:
https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2507

Or you can check the same sources here:
https://github.com/nterray/vimfiles/tree/master/.vim/autoload/railmoon

Comment: Well, what changed between Centos6 and Centos7? What Vim version did you use back then? What version do you use now? Did you even try to `:echo` this or that?

Comment: I used the same old, stable version on both systems Vim 7.0.
I installed v8.2, but the problem remains. All other stuff works correctly.